# Too Many open files/ No such host error while running a go program which makes concurrent requests

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a golang program which is supposed to call an API with different payloads, the web application is a drop wizard application which is running on localhost, and the go program is below

```
package main

import (
"bufio"
"encoding/json"
"log"
"net"
"net/http"
"os"
"strings"
"time"
)

type Data struct {
PersonnelId  string `json:"personnel_id"`
DepartmentId string `json:"department_id"`
}

type PersonnelEvent struct {
EventType string `json:"event_type"`
Data      `json:"data"`
}

const (
maxIdleConnections        = 20
maxIdleConnectionsPerHost = 20
timeout                   = time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
)

var transport = http.Transport{
Dial:                dialTimeout,
MaxIdleConns:        maxIdleConnections,
MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 20,
}

var client = &http.Client{
Transport: &transport,
}

func dialTimeout(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
}

func makeRequest(payload string) {
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:9350/v1/provider- 
location-personnel/index", strings.NewReader(payload))
req.Header.Set("X-App-Token", "TESTTOKEN1")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Api invocation returned an error ", err)
} else {
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    log.Println(resp.Body)
}
}

func indexPersonnels(personnelPayloads []PersonnelEvent) {
for _, personnelEvent := range personnelPayloads {
    payload, err := json.Marshal(personnelEvent)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while marshalling payload ", err)
    }
    log.Println(string(payload))
    // go makeRequest(string(payload))
  }
}

func main() {
ch := make(chan PersonnelEvent)
for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
    go func() {
        for personnelEvent := range ch {
            payload, err := json.Marshal(personnelEvent)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Error while marshalling payload", err)
            }
            go makeRequest(string(payload))
            //log.Println("Payload ", string(payload))
        }
    }()
}

file, err := os.Open("/Users/tmp/Desktop/personnels.txt")
defer file.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error opening personnel id file %v", err)
}
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scanner.Scan() {
    go func() {
        ch <- PersonnelEvent{EventType: "provider_location_department_personnel_linked", Data: Data{DepartmentId: "2a8d9687-aea8-4a2c-bc08-c64d7716d973", PersonnelId: scanner.Text()}}
    }()
}

}
```

Its reading some ids from a file and then creating a payload out of it and invoking a post request on the web server, but when i run the program it gives too many open file errors/no such host errors, i feel that the program is too much concurrent how to make it run gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your 20 goroutines started in main(), "go makeRequest(...)" again created one goroutine for each event. you don't need start extra goroutine there.
Besides, I think you don't need start goroutine in your scan loop, either. buffered channel is enough，because bottleneck should be at doing http requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a buffered channel, A.K.A. **counting semaphore**, to limit the parallelism.

```
// The capacity of the buffered channel is 10,
// which means you can have 10 goroutines to 
// run the makeRequest function in parallel.
var tokens = make(chan struct{}, 10)

func makeRequest(payload string) {
    tokens <- struct{}{}            // acquire the token or block here
    defer func() { <-tokens }()     // release the token to awake another goroutine
    // other code...
}
```

Comment: But i already am creating max 20 go routines in the main function right ? why doesn't that work @for_stack?

Comment: NO. There're more than 20 Goroutines. Since each of your 20 goroutine will create more Goroutines to call `makeRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @for_stack i understood the exact problem with the code, the issue was I'm creating more go routines inside the for loop which creates the 20 go routines